# Looks like I can do more in mod_proxy then mod_cluster?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

Looks like I can do more in mod_proxy then mod_cluster?

Attached is screen shots of them both but if you look with mod_proxy I can change Load Factor, LB Set, Routes, and more from the admin and I dont see this in mod_cluster.  is this true?

mod_proxy screen:
[image]

mod_cluster screen:

[image]

Comment: Belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a issue with Scientific Linux release 6.2 I had to tell it to stop blocking the port by doing the following command

setenforce 0

it works then. I got it working now